# Is there any table containing IATA codes for all countries in Microsoft Dynamics 2009

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

Is there any table which contains IATA (International Air Transport Association airport code)codes for all countries in Microsoft Dynamics 2009?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

It is trivial to create one though.

List of IATA codes: http://wisetravelsearch.com/Info/Airports/